# Is it possible to use the placeholder string twice?

Tags: c#, string, placeholder

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type a number");
            ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo1 = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Type another number");
            ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo2 = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("The number is {0}", KeyInfo1.KeyChar.ToString() + "The time is {1}. Is this right? Press y for yess or n for no.", KeyInfo2.KeyChar.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I'm asking this question is because the first number shows up in the console but the second number doesn't show up, it just says {1}. I hope this makes sense, I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of the `WriteLine` function is the format string.
Thats the part where you add placeholders.
You add the values to replace the placeholders as parameter after the first format parameter, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The number is {0} The time is {1}. Is this right? Press y for yess or n for no.", KeyInfo1.KeyChar.ToString(), KeyInfo2.KeyChar.ToString());
```

Where the first parameter (after format, ie, second paramater passed into the function) will replace `{0}` and the second will replace `{1}`.